# images in google sheet not display

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YyzAkaaK7WCm6aM1O2BOnbG58J5DbaG53TDA5Gs-XwI/edit#gid=1012084209

how to fix ?

my formula
=hyperlink(E2,IMAGE("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&right(E2,33)))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I applied [=Image(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"https://drive.google.com/open?id=","https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="))]  and if worked immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the value of "E2" is `https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileId}/view`. In this case, `right(E2,33)` is `{fileId}/view`. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In order to show the image, how about the following modification?

#### Modified formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(E2,IMAGE("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&INDEX(SPLIT(E2,"/"),0,5)))
```

and

```
=HYPERLINK(E2,IMAGE("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&REGEXEXTRACT(E2,"d\/(.+)\/")))
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the image is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful about this.

Comment: In this case 
if like this  "https://drive.google.com/open?id={google drive id}"
how to modify
i use this formula
=HYPERLINK(E2,IMAGE("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&INDEX(SPLIT(E2,"="),1,2))) 
is that right ?

Comment: @Jackky Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `In this case if like this "drive.google.com/open?id={google drive id}" how to modify i use this formula =HYPERLINK(E2,IMAGE("docs.google.com/…)) is that right ?`, in this case, how about `=IMAGE("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"="),0,2))`?